# Switching from babel-polyfill to core-js in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babel-polyfill

I use `babel-polyfill` in my `React` app to transpile `ECMAScript` to vanilla `JS`. I understand `babel-polyfill` is now deprecated.

The warning I get in my `React` app is:

> @babel/polyfill is deprecated. Please, use required parts of core-js
>   and regenerator-runtime/runtime separately

I currently have the following in my `package.json` file:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0"
  }
```

Is it safe to assume that I'll need to have the following now instead of `babel-polyfill`?

```
"devDependencies": {
    "core-js": "3.6.5",
    "regenerator-runtime": "0.13.5"
  },
```

Also, I think, instead of `import 'babel-polyfill';` in my reducers and components, I think I'll need the following:

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

Are these the steps to go through? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using CRA, just follow the steps here:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/main/packages/react-app-polyfill#polyfilling-other-language-features

Useful links:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7242